# Effects LEDs are uncomfortably bright - can they be dimmed? (Boss ME-70)

Tags: hardware

I use a Boss ME-70 multieffects unit and its red LEDs are uncomfortably bright. When I bend down to adjust a setting, it's like having a red laser shining in my eyes -- I can't even read the controls. I put black Pro-Touch labeler tape over the LEDs but that's a bit extreme. Anybody else bothered by the brightness and have a better solution?

Comment: Which LED's are you talking about specifically?

Comment: All the small circles (on/off lights).

Answer (score 9):

You might try a few layers of clear and/or colored nail polish

Comment: interesting idea.  have you tried this?  what did you use it on?

Comment: I've dimmed over bright LEDs with a black Sharpie and a light touch. Works great.

Comment: You can also take some 400+ grit sandpaper and rough up the plastic a little. It will refract the light slightly and cause it to go dim.

Comment: No, I haven't tried this yet. But it SHOULD work, and it comes off with nail polish remover if it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

There are two real options.

You can either modify the pedal electrically (replace the resistor that is connected to the LED for a larger value - thuis lowering the current through the LED).

Or you can modify the front of the pedal to decrease the light. A very easy way to do this is to tape a little bit of exposed film (like 35mm back when camera's used film), cut a little from the negative and slap it on with some tape, easily removable and should dim the light nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Tape a gel over the top. You can get cheap packs on ebay.

This would even allow you to adjust the level of filtration by combining them.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think tape is extreme, or a sharpie. But then I would probably just replace the LED's or pop a wee voltage drop in there to dim them down if they were that bad - this probably is extreme if you don't do home electronics much :-)

Tape is probably most sensible - as if you get a gig where you really need the lights you can always rip it off again.

Comment: Good point about gigs where you need the lights. I saw Beardyman play a festival in bright sunshine, in which he had huge problems because he couldn't see the LEDs on his Loopstation.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy some adhesives that will dim the led light for you.

For example, [ThinkGeek](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/eeb6/?srp=15) has a set that will just dim the led and another set that will completly black-out it.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this same problem on my audio interface on my Mac. I solve the problem by tilting it away from me a little bit. However, if you don't need to see the LEDs at all, I'd use some good ol' black electrical tape. It's easy to apply, and is removable. Then again, your labeler tape probably is as well.

Try putting tape on them in such a way that the tape is barely covering the LEDs, enough that the light peeks out over the edge, but also so that it shields *most* of the light. You can do the same thing with paint or nail polish, but it's more permanent.

Answer (score 0):

The hardcore route for this is to open up the pedal and slap larger resistors on the cathodes for each LED but you'll void the warranty doing that :D. The nail polish idea (care of @todd), roughing the plastic with a little 400+ grit sandpaper, or clear tape (care of @Neil Fein) are all good options.

Or you could go with some cheap sunglasses.

Answer (score 0):

I used some painter tape (I had some in blue, see https://amzn.to/3DpVKTD).
Cut 21x pieces of 12x8mm.
The blue tape mentioned above sticks nicely but you can remove it any time without leaving any trace. I also tested with eletrical tape (in white) but the painter tape in blue diffused those nasty lights better.